# accumulating a price with thresholds using javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This should be relatively easy but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I am making a pricing algorithms, which requires the following example addition

- £2.20p per bag between 12kg to 20kg

So I firstly need to determine whether the bag is over 12kg. That's the easy part. But! now I need to determine how many KGs that bag is over the thresholh of 12KG and add on the extra 2.20 for every KG it is over.

Thanks for any help in advanced!

H

Comment: If 12<kg<20, then the extra is 2.2*(kg-12)

Answer (score 0):

charleiftl - Granted it's not a mathematical site, but I literally just had no idea on how to set out my if statement to solve this issue, hence why I couldn't really give any sort of code. So apologies. I will make some up next time.

Elliopizzaman - Thank you very much for your answer that's all I wanted to know. Like I said it was pretty damn easy. I've just had a massive brain fart trying to solve it. Thanks Mate!!

Answer:

```
if(12 < KGs < 20) {
 2.20 x (KGs - 12);
}
```

...